# Parsing strings in batch

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have an **input directory** and an **output directory**.

My main goal is to read of the all files in the **input directory**, which are of a certain extension, into an array.

Then I wish to create the tree of directories of each file in the **input directory**, under the **output directory**.

For example:

**Input directory = `C:\Input`**

**Output directory = `C:\Output`**

**Input directory tree:**

`C:\Input\1\first.bat`

`C:\Input\2\3\second.bat`

`C:\Input\2\3\4\third.bat`

`C:\Input\3\1\forth.bat`

I wish the output tree, which is now empty of files and folders, to look like this:

**Output directory tree:**

`C:\Output\1\`

`C:\Output\2\3\`

`C:\Output\2\3\4\`

`C:\Output\3\1\`

I have the following code:

**For creating the array of files:**

```
    set k=0
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s %InputDir%\*.%StandardExtension%') do (
        set /a k+=1  
        set filesArray[!k!]=%%F 
    )
    set n=%k%
```

**Create the directory for each file:**

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
    set CurrentFile=!filesArray[%%i]!
    call :CheckAndCreateDirectory %SequencesDir% !CurrentFile! %OutputDir% UpdatedOutputDir
)
```

**And finally, the function which creates the directories:**

```
:CheckAndCreateDirectory
set IntputDir=%1
set CurrentDir=%~dp2
set OutputDir=%3

set UpdatedOutputDir=!CurrentDir:%IntputDir%=%OutputDir%!
set %4=%UpdatedOutputDir%

if not exist %UpdatedOutputDir% (^
echo. & ^
mkdir %UpdatedOutputDir% & ^
echo.)
```

The thing is this:
If the input (and I guess output also) don't contain any "special" characters like `&` etc., the code works.
However, if it does, the directories tree is not created.

**Working input: `C:\Input_Dir`**

**Not working input: `C:\Input&Dir`**

Any ideas?

Comment: Kayasax has provided you with a much better solution. The reason your code failed is because the special character was neither escaped nor quoted. The simplest solution is to quote the various paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i've a simplier solution for you :

```
xcopy /T c:\input c:\ouptut
```

Some details :

> /T           Create folder structure, but do not copy files. Do not
>                   include empty folders or subfolders. 
>                   /T /E will include empty folders and subfolders.

Comment: ok, first, thanks a lot, that solves the problem. Now I have another issue. I'm trying to create a new file path for each file, so, for: `C:\input\file.exe` I wish to create: `C:\output\file.new.bat` how can I do that?

Comment: here is a way but not supporting recursivity : `copy c:\input\*.exe c:\output\*.new.bat`

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Kaysax looks good, but to answer your original question:
Use delayed expansion always.
And try to enclose your arguments into quotes like

```
mkdir "!UpdatedOutputDir!"
```

The point is, that delayed expansion can handle all special characters without problems.

The only problem left is in your loops, as you can lose exclamation marks `!` in file or pathnames, as the FOR-loop-parameters are expanded just before the delayed expansion occours.
To solve this, much more effort is necessary.